# Ensure that devices connect to a specific access point

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I have the following setup in my apartment:

A Fritz!Box is connected to the internet and broadcasts my wifi signal. To improve reception, a TP Link router configured as  access point is connected through a powerline adapter to serve the other side of the apartment. The TP link runs dd-wrt. Only the Fritz!Box runs a DHCP server.

I now bought a Sonos speaker which will stand more or less exactly at the spot where the two signals from the TP Link and the Fritz!Box overlap. Since powerline is [not supported](https://support.sonos.com/s/article/126?language=en) by Sonos (and does cause some trouble in my setup), I would like to ensure that the Sonos always connects to the wifi signal from the Fritz!Box, not the TP Link.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Set up MAC filtering on the TP Link to prevent the Sonos from connecting to the AP

Comment: Easiest way is to use two different SSIDs. Sonos speaker should be configured to connect to only one of those, all other devices can be configured to connect to either. That said, "powerline is not supported by Sonos" makes no sense - an access point is an access point. If you need a single subnet for the Sonos speaker to work, fix your network configuration.

Comment: @Kinnectus I was thinking about MAC filtering already, but was afraid that it might continuously try to connect to the TP Link but not to the main router

Comment: @dirkt that would be the best approach, however if the Sonos speakers receive a signal from the likes of a connected mobile phone (i.e. stream from phone) then two SSIDs wouldn't usually be connected to the same subnet so the devices wouldn't be able to communicate (i.e. a "home" and "guest" wifi). If the Fritzbox has VLAn capability then you might be in business

Comment: @TillB - try it. DD-WRT is very configurable.... it'll either work or it won't...

Comment: @dirkt I would like to avoid different SSIDs. The fact that "powerline is not supported" comes from Sonos themselves, though I did not understand why. I did have trouble, when it was connected through the powerline (random disconnects). What do you mean by "fix your network config"? Do you mean something specific?

Comment: also I am pretty sure that both APs use the same subnet, will check when I am back home

Comment: @TillB - if you're referring to my comment then that'll only be an issue if your Fritzbox has multiple SSID capability and whether or not it forces different subnets (to ensure the two networks can't talk to each other - think home and guest networks) or whether the subnets are configurable or if the Fritzbox has any VLAn capability to allow the two wireless networks to be able to talk to each other..

Comment: @Kinnectus No, I was referring to dirkt's comment regarding fixing network configuration if I need a single subnet.

Comment: Please edit your question with a link or a description what Sonos themselves say about why powerline is not supported (powerline can have lower bandwidth, which may cause the disconnects, but that's not powerline specific; it also can happen on a WLAN with bad reception and low bandwidth). Please also add a detailed description about your network setup (subnets? Double NAT?). Then I probably can say something specific.

Comment: @dirkt I added I link to Sonos's description, but it does not give any reasons. I spoke to support yesterday, but when I kept pushing about why I can stream 4k on Netflix or play LoL, he got annoyed and murmured a couple of abreviations I did not understand.

Comment: Both wifis are in the same subnet (subnet mask is 255.255.255.0, IP adresses are 192.168.178.X). What other information do you need?

Comment: What I observe when either the Sonos or my mobile is connected via Powerline is that sometimes the app does not connect to the Sonos.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

According to the Sonos description, the problem seems to be the delay when using a powerline adapter, not the powerline adapter itself.

So this means the Sonos is only usable by applications connecting to the same access point (AP), whichever you choose. Because if Sonos is connected to one AP and the Application to the other, the powerline between both routers will cause the delay.

Given that, I'd really recommend the two SSID approach - this will mean you'll clearly know which devices can use the Sonos and which can't.

If you don't do this and use one SSID, even if you manage to coerce the Sonos to connect to the AP you want, a device with an application using Sonos could still silently connect to the other AP (or decide to switch while being connected), leading to the above problems.